# Youtube tags that describe the videos description in a short video with a long description?

Tags: spam, youtube, tags, terms-of-use, accounts

I have a short video on Youtube, with a long description thats like a story about the video.

I want to put in a couple of dozen tags that describe/categorise the text in the description. This is not typical, and the video itself is still an important part, but for this specific video the native in the description contains much of the relevant content.

I'm not expecting many if any views but want to go through this process anyway, it may well be able to turn up in serches on long tail tags I've used.

---

Is Youtube going to object to this being tag spam if it doesn't look like most the tags describe the video itself?

Answer (score 1):

Google has not released any information about SEO & Youtube, but remember: Google owns Youtube.

You can see Google in action about not releasing information, here: [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/hN7S6p_oSyE)

But since Google runs the show, I would recommend following SEO advice for `meta keywords` in an HTML page the same way it is for Youtube tags. For that reason, I would personally not recommend more than 10 tags maximum, 5 tags being pretty solid. This is a matter of opinion though.

An additional theory out there is that the more tags there are, the more the SEO emphasis is split up among those tags, giving each tag only a fraction of the attention compared to having one tag.

It is unnecessary to have concatenated tags, such as "#peachcobbler #peach #cobbler". Google is way smarter than that. It's not worth dividing keyword attention 3-fold to cover different hyphenation.

This is mostly subject matter of opinion, but hopefully this helps you understand what the general picture consists of.

Comment: It's very useful info. I was more concerned in the question about breaking the rules regarding account action against videos with lots of unrelated tags. Optimisation wise, "peach cobbler" might be a good long tail search, other advice suggests that using Peach and Cobbler in separate tags instead would be seached more often, but would appear much further down the results for those words than the "peach cobbler" tag would for that more specific search.

Comment: It makes soo much sense that the more tags you have the less they each contribute, I couldn't find this info in other reasonably long articles on the subject.

Comment: Funny thing is that there are mixed results for maximum number of tags, there is no definitive answer for that either. Hmm